# How to remove stop words from documents in gensim?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I'm building a NLP chat application using Doc2Vec technique in Python using its `gensim` package. I have already done tokenizing and stemming. I want to remove the stop words (to test if it works better) from both the training set as well as the question which user throws.

Here is my code.

```
import gensim
import nltk
from gensim import models
from gensim import utils
from gensim import corpora
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
ps = PorterStemmer()

sentence0 = models.doc2vec.LabeledSentence(words=[u'sampl',u'what',u'is'],tags=["SENT_0"])
sentence1 = models.doc2vec.LabeledSentence(words=[u'sampl',u'tell',u'me',u'about'],tags=["SENT_1"])
sentence2 = models.doc2vec.LabeledSentence(words=[u'elig',u'what',u'is',u'my'],tags=["SENT_2"])
sentence3 = models.doc2vec.LabeledSentence(words=[u'limit', u'what',u'is',u'my'],tags=["SENT_3"])
sentence4 = models.doc2vec.LabeledSentence(words=[u'claim',u'how',u'much',u'can',u'I'],tags=["SENT_4"])
sentence5 = models.doc2vec.LabeledSentence(words=[u'retir',u'i',u'am',u'how',u'much',u'can',u'elig',u'claim'],tags=["SENT_5"])
sentence6 = models.doc2vec.LabeledSentence(words=[u'resign',u'i',u'have',u'how',u'much',u'can',u'i',u'claim',u'elig'],tags=["SENT_6"])
sentence7 = models.doc2vec.LabeledSentence(words=[u'promot',u'what',u'is',u'my',u'elig',u'post',u'my'],tags=["SENT_7"])
sentence8 = models.doc2vec.LabeledSentence(words=[u'claim',u'can,',u'i',u'for'],tags=["SENT_8"])
sentence9 = models.doc2vec.LabeledSentence(words=[u'product',u'coverag',u'cover',u'what',u'all',u'are'],tags=["SENT_9"])
sentence10 = models.doc2vec.LabeledSentence(words=[u'hotel',u'coverag',u'cover',u'what',u'all',u'are'],tags=["SENT_10"])
sentence11 = models.doc2vec.LabeledSentence(words=[u'onlin',u'product',u'can',u'i',u'for',u'bought',u'through',u'claim',u'sampl'],tags=["SENT_11"])
sentence12 = models.doc2vec.LabeledSentence(words=[u'reimburs',u'guidelin',u'where',u'do',u'i',u'apply',u'form',u'sampl'],tags=["SENT_12"])
sentence13 = models.doc2vec.LabeledSentence(words=[u'reimburs',u'procedur',u'rule',u'and',u'regul',u'what',u'is',u'the',u'for'],tags=["SENT_13"])
sentence14 = models.doc2vec.LabeledSentence(words=[u'can',u'i',u'submit',u'expenditur',u'on',u'behalf',u'of',u'my',u'friend',u'and',u'famili',u'claim',u'and',u'reimburs'],tags=["SENT_14"])
sentence15 = models.doc2vec.LabeledSentence(words=[u'invoic',u'bills',u'procedur',u'can',u'i',u'submit',u'from',u'shopper stop',u'claim'],tags=["SENT_15"])
sentence16 = models.doc2vec.LabeledSentence(words=[u'invoic',u'bills',u'can',u'i',u'submit',u'from',u'pantaloon',u'claim'],tags=["SENT_16"])
sentence17 = models.doc2vec.LabeledSentence(words=[u'invoic',u'procedur',u'can',u'i',u'submit',u'invoic',u'from',u'spencer',u'claim'],tags=["SENT_17"])

# User asks a question.

document = input("Ask a question:")
tokenized_document = list(gensim.utils.tokenize(document, lowercase = True, deacc = True))
#print(type(tokenized_document))
stemmed_document = []
for w in tokenized_document:
    stemmed_document.append(ps.stem(w))
sentence19 = models.doc2vec.LabeledSentence(words= stemmed_document, tags=["SENT_19"])

# Building vocab.
sentences = [sentence0,sentence1,sentence2,sentence3, sentence4, sentence5,sentence6, sentence7, sentence8, sentence9, sentence10, sentence11, sentence12, sentence13, sentence14, sentence15, sentence16, sentence17, sentence19]

#I tried to remove the stop words but it didn't work out as LabeledSentence object has no attribute lower.
stoplist = set('for a of the and to in'.split())
texts = [[word for word in document.lower().split() if word not in stoplist]
          for document in sentences]
..
```

Is there a way I can remove stop words from `sentences` directly and get a new set of vocab without stop words ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `sentences` object is a already a list of `LabeledSentence` objects. You construct these above; they include a list-of-strings in `words` and a list-of-strings in `tags`.

So each item in that list (`document` in your list-comprehension) can't have a string method like `.lower()` applied to it. (Nor would it need to be `.split()`, as its `words` are already separate tokens.)

The cleanest approach would be to remove stop-words from the lists-of-words *before* they're used to construct `LabeledSentence` objects. For example, you could make a function `without_stopwords()`, defined at the top. Then your lines creating `LabeledSentence` objects could instead be like:

```
sentence0 = LabeledSentence(words=remove_stopwords([u'sampl', u'what', u'is']), 
                            tags=["SENT_0"])
```

Alternatively, you could *mutate* the existing `LabeledSentence` objects so that each of their `words` attributes now lack stop-words. This would replace your last line with something more like:

```
for doc in sentences:
    doc.words = [word for word in doc.words if word not in stoplist]
texts = sentences
```

Separately, things you didn't ask but should know:

- `TaggedDocument` is now the preferred example-class name for Doc2Vec text objects – but in fact any object that has the two required properties `words` and `tags` will work fine.
- Doc2Vec doesn't show many of the desired properties on tiny, toy-sized datasets – don't be surprised if a model built on dozens of sentences does not do anything useful, or misleads about what preprocessing/meta-parameter options are best. (Tens of thousands of texts, and texts at least tens-of-words long, are much better for meaningful results.)
- Much Word2Vec/Doc2Vec work doesn't bother with stemming or stop-word removal, but it may sometimes be helpful.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It isn't accurate and gives wrong cosine similarity most of the time but it can't be helped..That's the data provided to me.  Thats why I am trying to check whether stemming or stop word removal will help.  Can you also suggest me a better approach to build a question-answering system when I have a list of sample questions and answers. Thanks.

Comment: A question-answering system is a pretty broad realm & what may work could need a lot more than Doc2Vec, & depend on how much and what kind of QA data you have. For simple similarity of new Qs with previous Qs, Doc2Vec might work – but you'd need a *lot* more training data. There's also an interesting technique for sentence-similarity called "Word Mover's Distance", which needs just words (not per-doc-trained vectors). It might work for finding most-similar earlier Qs. It's available on gensim Word2Vec/KeyedVectors as `wmdistance()` – but is quite slow to compute pairwise on large datasets.